# Excel VBA Workbook Printout Method

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA macro to convert excel workbooks to PDF.
The wkb.PrintOut method works fine for some excel files. But for the others, it will print the first worksheet to the file name I supplied, and prompt me for the file name to save for the remaining worksheets.

Why does the PrintOut function behaves such a way? How do I let it print the entire workbook into a single file name I set?

```
Public Sub ConvertToPDF()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim inputQueue As Collection
Dim outputQueue As Collection
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objInputFolder As Folder
Dim objOutputFolder As Folder
Dim objInputFile As File
Dim fileExt As String

Set ws = Worksheets("XLPrint")
Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
Set inputQueue = New Collection
Set outputQueue = New Collection
Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
r = ws.Range("folder_name").Row + 1
c = ws.Range("folder_name").Column

ClearCollection inputQueue
ClearCollection outputQueue

While (ws.Cells(r, c).Value <> "")
    inputQueue.Add objFSO.GetFolder(ws.Cells(r, c).Value)
    outputQueue.Add objFSO.GetFolder(ws.Cells(r, c + 1).Value)
    r = r + 1
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While inputQueue.Count > 0
    Set objInputFolder = inputQueue(1)
    inputQueue.Remove 1
    Set objOutputFolder = outputQueue(1)
    outputQueue.Remove 1

    For Each objInputFile In objInputFolder.Files
        fileExt = Mid(objInputFile.ShortName, InStr(objInputFile.ShortName, ".") + 1)
        Select Case UCase(fileExt)
            Case "XLSX", "XLSM", "XLS"
                Call PrintXLToPDF(objInputFile, objOutputFolder)
            Case "DOCX", "DOC"
                Call PrintWordToPDF(objInputFile, objOutputFolder)
        End Select
    Next objInputFile
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set inputQueue = Nothing
Set outputQueue = Nothing
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

Public Sub PrintXLToPDF(ByVal objInputXL As File, ByVal objOutputFolder As Folder)

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim outputFileName As String

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(objInputXL.Path)
outputFileName = objOutputFolder.ShortPath & "\" & Mid(objInputXL.Name, 1, InStr(objInputXL.Name, ".") - 1) & ".pdf"
wkb.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, PrToFileName:=outputFileName, ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:"
wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set wkb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe save it before you print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just saving it directly as PDF instead of printing:

```
wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=outputFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks

I combined the Plagon's answer and the answer of the
HackSlash and my problem was solved

The problem is solved when you save the Woorkbook (`ActiveWorkbook.Save`) and then use the line suggested by HackSlash:

```
wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=outputFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
```